# Shrink Wrap Modifier and Distortion

Tags: modifiers

I have created two cables that wrap around each other.

I want to apply a foil shield, so I created a cylinder, deleted the top and bottom faces then applied a shrink wrap modifier.

It worked, however, the top and bottom of the wrapped cylinder (marked in red) is distorted instead of a nice straight top and bottom edge, I really wanted a straight line. Please see the reference images.

[[image: before wrap]

[image: after wrap]

Comment: Have you tried different wrap methods. Above looks like "Nearest Surface Point".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... Yes, I have selected all of the options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the options, with the same successs :( so ... what about Booleans?

- to help a bit topology, use Simple Deform Modifier > Twist
- ShrinkWrap >
- Smooth Modifier > Repeat 5
- add a Cube and for Cylinder add Boolean Modifier > Intersect

(if you plan to move Cylinder, would be better to parent (Ctrl+P) Cube to Cylinder)

[image]

- to smooth surface - search for Smooth Shading
- fix for edges shading - go to Properties Editor > Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth

(like that Subsurface Modifier probably is not needed in this case)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Vklidu, thanks for the detailed instructions. Now I can't even get the foil to wrap correctly. I dont know what i've done differently. I even downloaded your blender file and copied it to no avail. Please see link

(https://ibb.co/bzgChsh)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I see on screenshot, send me the blend, but first check Transform > Scale if its set in all axis (XYZ) to 1 if not Apply (Ctrl+A) Scale. Or set manually back to 1 and extend cylinder by array modifier. Seems to me like you scaled the cylinder object in Z axis.

Comment: I have uploaded a file, with the issues as described, be grateful if you can take a look?
[FILE HERE](https://gofile.io/?c=O126qw)

Comment: Your cables used Scale Transformation, as I sayed Ctr+A solved distortion. Fixed file https://gofile.io/?c=ZlQ8jS

Comment: Hi, I downloaded your file, and it is a distorted plane.

I reset all using CTRL+A so the scale of the cylinder to be shrink-wrapped reads 1,1,1 in all axis, however after applying the shrink wrap, I get the same distorted appearance?

Comment: Sorry, I applied the transforms to the shield, not the cables, I applied to the cables and it worked.
thank you so much for all of your help! I am more thankful than you will ever know!!!